# OBSOLETE - GeeQe - Native Stack Overflow client

Tags: app, obsolete, iphone

> ### Obsolete - no longer in iTunes store, no source code given, and was coded for a decommissioned version of the API.

### About

The Geek Question Explorer is a Native Stack Overflow iPhone Application.

GeeQe has been updated to use the Stack Exchange API for everything except search results. I am looking for some feedback on what features people would be interested in seeing next. The short list I have is:

- Adding push notifications for watched posts. Right now you can bookmark posts but I also have disabled code in the client that would allow you to watch a post as well.
- Adding push notifications for tags, etc. I'm not sure how practical this is given the volume but if you have suggestions I'm interested.
- Adding the ability to use other Stack Exchange sites. I'm not sure how many people will really want to use this outside of Stack Overflow but if there is enough interest I'll add the ability.
- Move the "Explore" tab to the first position and add things like Hot, Recent, etc to the list.

### Screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Features

- Post searching
- Post bookmarks
- User searching
- Claim your user profile
- Browse the original post on StackOverflow.com

#### License

MIT or GPL when I get around to releasing the code.

#### Download

Dead link <del>[iTunes store link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/geeqe/id330493203?mt=8)</del>

#### Platform

iPhone OS 3+

### Contact

geeqe@ioncannon.net

### Code

I've planed on releasing the code for over a year but I'm not happy with the quality currently. I will try to get it into better shape with the next version and release it all.

Comment: "I'm not sure how many people will really want to use this outside of Stack Overflow" - trust me, there's plenty. Me for one. I don't use Stack Overflow. I think I have one question on there. But SF and the new Pro Webmasters? All over it.

Comment: Whats the status of the source code release?